# cannot install conda install bob.db.replay on windows subsytem for linux in a python 3.8 environment?

Tags: conda, windows-subsystem-for-linux, python-3.8, python-bob

[image: conda install bob.db.replay]

I followed the instructions for installing bob channels here at https://www.idiap.ch/software/bob/docs/bob/docs/stable/install.html and still, I can't install bob.db.replay. Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install conda.db.replay on WSL,Run these codes below

1.conda install -n base -c conda-forge mamba. should you get a warning to upgrade to a newer version of conda, run conda update -n base conda otherwise ignore the conda update should you not receive a warning message to upgrade to a newer conda version

2.mamba update -n base -c conda-forge conda mamba

3. conda config --set show_channel_urls True

Create an environment with the specific Bob packages that you need. For example if you want to install bob.pad.base, bob.pad.face, pytorch and other appropriate/suitable packages you need for bob package:

4. mamba create --name bob_env1 --override-channels 
   -c https://www.idiap.ch/software/bob/conda 
   -c conda-forge 
   python=3 bob.pad.base bob.io.video bob.db.base bob.pad.face
   bob.pipelines bob.learn.em  pytorch
5. Then activate the environment and configure its channels to make sure the channel list is correct in the future as well:

conda activate bob_env1
$ conda config --env --add channels conda-forge
$ conda config --env --add channels https://www.idiap.ch/software/bob/conda

6. Navigate to this site https://gitlab.idiap.ch/bob/bob.db.replay/-/tree/master/ and clone it. cd into the requirements.txt file and install using pip or pip3 install -r requirements.txt and you will get the following output, this will be different for your computer

Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /home/adesoji/viper/envs/bob_env1/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (59.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /home/adesoji/viper/envs/bob_env1/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 2)) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: sqlalchemy in /home/adesoji/viper/envs/bob_env1/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 3)) (1.4.40)
Requirement already satisfied: bob.db.base in /home/adesoji/viper/envs/bob_env1/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 4)) (3.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: bob.io.video in /home/adesoji/viper/envs/bob_env1/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 5)) (3.0.5)
Requirement already satisfied: greenlet!=0.4.17 in /home/adesoji/viper/envs/bob_env1/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from sqlalchemy->-r requirements.txt (line 3)) (1.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: bob.io.image in /home/adesoji/viper/envs/bob_env1/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from bob.db.base->-r requirements.txt (line 4)) (2.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: bob.extension in /home/adesoji/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from bob.db.base->-r requirements.txt (line 4)) (7.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: bob.io.base in /home/adesoji/viper/envs/bob_env1/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from bob.db.base->-r requirements.txt (line 4)) (4.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow in /home/adesoji/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from bob.io.video->-r requirements.txt (line 5)) (9.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: bob.blitz in /home/adesoji/viper/envs/bob_env1/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from bob.io.video->-r requirements.txt (line 5)) (2.0.24)
Requirement already satisfied: bob.core in /home/adesoji/viper/envs/bob_env1/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from bob.io.video->-r requirements.txt (line 5)) (2.2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: click-plugins in /home/adesoji/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from bob.extension->bob.db.base->-r requirements.txt (line 4)) (1.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=8 in /home/adesoji/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from bob.extension->bob.db.base->-r requirements.txt (line 4)) (8.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /home/adesoji/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from bob.blitz->bob.io.video->-r requirements.txt (line 5)) (1.19.2)

7. Now you can run your [image: Successfully Installed the Requirements.txt for bob.db.replay]Replay Attack Database Database Interface for Bob

Answer (score 0):

You do not have the correct channels configured, and also you should follow the instructions of installing an older version of Bob as described in: https://www.idiap.ch/software/bob/docs/bob/docs/stable/install.html. Please try:

```
conda create -n bob_env1 \
 -c https://www.idiap.ch/software/bob/conda \
 -c conda-forge \
 -c https://www.idiap.ch/software/bob/conda/label/archive \
 bob.db.replay
```

And also note that all `bob.db` packages are deprecated. Database interfaces are included inside the respective packages directly such as `bob.bio.face` or `bob.pad.face`.

Comment: please can you show me in a demonstration via sharing of my screen, i have tried installing it but have not been able to still following the link you provided me. Thank you